# PHP scraping & preg_replace

Tags: php, html, arrays, curl

I'm scraping weather information of one meteo station and trying to convert it into database format.

I scraped from the web page the data I need, but when I try to replace all the matches in my code it only does it once and also I still don't know how to convert it into an array. the array i'm trying to do is something like (date, time, variable, value). I need the array to put it into a .txt file and a database later.

this is what i've got so far:

```
 <?php;

 function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); // miro que quito todo antes de start
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
    return $data;   // devuelvo data entre las sentencias

}
// Defining the basic cURL function
$url = 'http://aprs.fi/?c=raw&call=EA4RKU-13&limit=1000&view=normal';
$ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
$data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable

$start="<div class='browselist_data'>";
$end = '</div>';

$data = scrape_between($data, $start, $end); // me quedo con la parte con span

curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
//echo strip_tags($data); // quita todos los tags html y php deja feo

 $z = count($data);

 echo "numero de datos: " .$z; //echo $data;   // Returning the data from the function
 $data1=preg_replace('/<b>.+?<\/b>/im', '' ,$data);
 //$data1=preg_replace('/<b>.+?<\/b>/im', '' ,$data);
 $data1=preg_replace('/$<a>.+?<\/a>/', '', $data1);
 echo $data1;

 ?>
```

Comment: Just FYI, the term is "scraping", not "scrapping" - I've submitted an edit to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the stristr and stripos, you could use something like this:

```
<?
  ...

  preg_match_all("|<span class='raw_line'>(.*?)</span>|is",$data,$lines);
  echo count($lines[1]); //number of lines

?>
```

Also, you should explain better what do you need from each line? What kind of output do you expect? Can you show an example?

Comment: ok, i will try this and what i need is an information from span to span and from each line i need the date, time, the name of the variable after :4030.25N/00320.45W_, and the value.

There are 20 variables, but sometimes one value doesn't appear, so i need to check the name of the variable.

As an example from each line i need this:

<span class='raw_line'>2014-02-24 13:24:58 CET: &gt;APRS,WIDE2-2,qAR,<a href='http://aprs.fi/?c=raw&amp;limit=&amp;call=EA4RKU'>EA4RKU</a>:=4030.25N/00320.45W_HS:-0.07</span><br />

2014-02-24 13:24:58 HS -0.07

Comment: Also with your suggestion i get the number of lines, but not the data, so i use both of them

Comment: `$lines[1]` contains your lines. Do `print_r($lines[1])` and see what you get - lines which you need.

Comment: i understand that, but then the manual says that in $lines[1] has the amount of lines of the information wich matches without span tags, so why can't i access $lines[1][$i]

Comment: Did you do `print_r($lines[1])`? What does that give you?

Comment: Ok i found the problem, i made too many request to the page today so i created the same one on my localhost to try it and it works. and i reamoved some useless information with this : $lines[1][$i]=preg_replace('/<b>.+?<\/b>/im', '' ,$lines[1][$i]);

Comment: it gives me the data beetween <span> tags and if i do a for it shows me all the data.